# +/- 1 month to the datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

What will happen when I minus 1 month to the datetime when the datetime's month falls on December? Vice versa to plus 1 month too.

Will the new datetime's year automatically change accordingly?

Thanks~

Comment: Yes, you could write a very quick program to test this

Comment: Well it won't change if you subtract a month in December. Yes, it will if you add a month. I wrote a program to test this in 163 characters (indented, clean, nice names). Your post is 203 characters. *Please* do research before asking questions.

Comment: [A Very quick program (Not so nice names though!)](https://ideone.com/iDs54K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year does automatically change with adding and subtracting months. See [This Example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E77vX3)